# How does Data from Synapse SQL DW gets transferred to Power BI?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, powerbi-datasource, azure-synapse, azure-security

I am importing data from SQL DW to Power Bi using SQL server authentication credentials. [image: Power-bi-desktop-screenshot]

I read in this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/use-data-gateways-sources-power-bi) that VNets can be used as Data gateways for various Power BI Data sources. Can this be applied here? Transfer of data from Synapse SQL DW to Power BI service will always happen through public internet or can it happen through VNets also?

I am new with these services, so my question could be silly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can connect through public internet as well as from private vnet(data gateway).

Virtual network data gateways allows import or direct query datasets to connect to data services within an Azure VNet without the need of an on-premises data gateway.

as per the doc you are following  VNet data gateways will support connectivity to the following Azure data services:

1.Azure SQL

2.Azure Synapse Analytics

3.Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)

4.Azure Table Storage

5.Azure Blob Storage

6.Azure HDInsight (Spark)

7.Azure Data Lake (Gen2)

8.Cosmos DB

Note:The The virtual network (VNet) data gateway is still in preview. and Virtual network data gateways is a premium-only feature, and will be available only in Power BI Premium workspaces and Premium Per User (PPU) for public preview. However, licensing requirements might change when VNet data gateways become generally available.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-azure-sql-data-warehouse-with-direct-connect)

[Create virtual network data gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/create-data-gateways)

Comment: Will it be a public internet or azure network with some security layer?
When I just normally click on 'Get Data' and navigate to SQL DW and give my SQL credentials, will it happen through public internet? Will it be not secure?

My understanding of data gateway was if there is some on-premise data that need to be transferred, then only we should go for data gateways. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: by default if your connecting to the data source in azure the connection will be public and traffic is encrypted, if you want connect from specific vnet over a private connection you can go with vnet data gateway option. On-premises data gateway: Allows multiple users to connect to multiple on-premises data sources. With a single gateway installation, .In addition, there's a virtual network (VNet) data gateway that lets multiple users connect to multiple data sources that are secured by virtual networks. No installation is required